# How to solve error on docker:layers_calculator to compute the Merkle tree on private tangle?

Tags: docker-compose, bazel, directed-acyclic-graphs, compass, iota

I want to setup a private tangle on my own virtual machine with Ubuntu 18.04, 4GB RAM and 20GB memory.
I have follow this instructions: https://docs.iota.org/docs/compass/0.1/how-to-guides/set-up-a-private-tangle. Every command works fine until reach this one: `bazel run //docker:layers_calculator`.
It shows an error as follows:

```
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
ERROR: /home/istabraq/compass/third-party/maven_deps.bzl:3:5: Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/istabraq/compass/WORKSPACE", line 42
        maven_jars()
    File "/home/istabraq/compass/third-party/maven_deps.bzl", line 3, in maven_jars
        native.maven_jar(<4 more arguments>)
type 'struct' has no method maven_jar()
ERROR: error loading package '': Encountered error while reading extension file 'protobuf_deps.bzl': no such package '@com_google_protobuf_deps//': error loading package 'external': Could not load //external package
ERROR: error loading package '': Encountered error while reading extension file 'protobuf_deps.bzl': no such package '@com_google_protobuf_deps//': error loading package 'external': Could not load //external package
INFO: Elapsed time: 4.743s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded)
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded)
```

How can I solve this problem? what I have missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve this issue by using this commands:

Step 3: Set up your environment
If you ran the Bazel installer with the --user flag as above, the Bazel executable is installed in your $HOME/bin directory. It’s a good idea to add this directory to your default paths, as follows:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin"
```

You can also add this command to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` file to make it permanent.

reference:
https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/install-ubuntu.html

Answer (score 0):

read carefully the message given after running bazel installer:

Make sure you have "/home/yourusername/bin" in your path. You can also activate bash completion by adding the following line to your :
  source /home/yourusername/.bazel/bin/bazel-complete.bash

You can check with: "bazel info" or "bazel version"

Unfortunately, there are further errors:
https://github.com/iotaledger/compass/issues/142

Comment: Thank you for answering the question, but try to provide more detail and explanation to your answer. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question

Comment: please give me more details how to sure with this path "/home/yourusername/bin" and how to activate hash completion?